# Laravel firstOrCreate not merging the search entry

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm

There's plenty of other questions surrounding this where people were using it wrong, but I'm confident I have the proper syntax and it's just leaving out the search term by the time it makes it to sql.

I've done 2 iterations. One where I add the 'sub' again and one where I don't

```
   protected function upsertUser( $profile ) {  
        $sub  = $profile['sub'];
        $email = $profile['email'];
        $name = $profile['name'];
        Log::stack(['single'])->critical(compact("sub", "email", "name"));
        return User::firstOrCreate(compact("sub"), ['sub' => $profile['sub'], 'email' => $profile['email'] ?? '', 'name' => $profile['name'] ?? '']);
    }
```

```
   protected function upsertUser( $profile ) {  
        $sub  = $profile['sub'];
        $email = $profile['email'];
        $name = $profile['name'];
        Log::stack(['single'])->critical(compact("sub", "email", "name"));
        return User::firstOrCreate(compact("sub"), ['email' => $profile['email'] ?? '', 'name' => $profile['name'] ?? '']);
    }
```

In both cases, sub just doesn't make it to the creation failing with:
[A message showing that it doesn't even try to insert 'sub'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Bcn.png)

Logging the array shows that it contains the desired data.

Now I had come across a post where someone suggested that it was mass assignment protection stopping me from adding sub. I don't think it's related, but I tried to add

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'sub',
    ];
```

To the users model but it did not help. I do not want to allow nullable, because I need that data.

Comment: Your first solution with $fillable should work.

Comment: The first solution shows the same message when `$fillable` contains `'sub'`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It didn't work with fillable. It's been a while since I've done this, but even if that was the case, isn't there a mass fillable exception? Like I don't think it's supposed to fail silently, although I might be mistaken

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I figured it out, I made a dumb mistake

Answer (score 0):

So this was terrible. I'm following along with this Auth0 sample app guide and in this sample they have a users model. I think this is default to laravel.

App/models/users != App/user

I had to make sub fillable on that "model" it's not even a traditional model it extends Auth\User